# Is there a YouTube keyboard shortcut for the previous and next video in a playlist?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, youtube-playlist

I have a YouTube playlist and would like to know whether there are keyboard shortcuts to move to a previous video or advance to a next video. This will be helpful instead of moving to click the bottom bar every time.

Comment: You can use Shift+N (next) and Shift+P (previous) to navigate through a playlist. But keep in mind that the playlist is kind of like on long video so if you start from the top (most recent video) of the playlist and you just let it play it will automatically go to the next one down in the playlist.

Answer (score 45):

Yup, you can! <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is next video in playlist and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is the previous one!

Comment: I don't know if this is a recent development, but this definitely works and is the best solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

After the recent development, YouTube is now able to do that.

> **Shift+N**:  Move to the next video (If you are using a playlist, will go
>   to the next video of the playlist. If not using a playlist, it will
>   move to the next YouTube suggested video)
>
> **Shift+P**:  Move to the previous video. Note that this shortcut only works when you are using a playlist.
>
> **Next Track Media Key on keyboards**:    Moves to the next track in a play/list.

You can see the full list of YouTube keyboard shortcuts [here](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189278).

Comment: This might be recent, but according to the link you posted: `Next Track Media Key on keyboards: Moves to the next track in a play/list`

Comment: They have added undocumented keyboard shortcut now. See answer by Gal Peric.

Comment: Also of interest, shift-chevrons adjust speed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to click in the video to get focus first, but the below are keyboard shortcuts:

- Space is pause/play
- Shift-N is next track (or backspace)
- Shift-P is previous track
- F is fullcreen/resize

Answer (score 1):

You can use either <kbd>9</kbd> or the <kbd>end</kbd> key to reach near the end of the video. This should advance you to the next video in the selection.

For the previous video hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (PC) or <kbd>Delete</kbd> (On Mac).

Comment: none of this works in W7 and Chrome, but in fullscreen repeated right arrow moves to end of video then to next

Comment: Just tested this in Chrome; <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>end</kdb> works. Context: Clicked the video interface so that it has focus, then used those shortcuts, Chrome version `40.0.2214.45 beta-m`, on youtube.com, while watching a video, that is part of a playlist.

Answer (score 1):

On April 11th, 2012 at 10:25 - user18941 stated that the shortcut keys (e.g. 9/END) do not work on Windows 7/Chrome (not sure if he means that combination, or any combination containing one of the two) but that's incorrect. The reason why it doesn't appear to work is because the flash player is out of focus by default. If you click the video once, then use one of the hotkeys, they work.

So the solution would be to automatically focus the player on pageload. You could do this with a big bulky jQuery script, or you could use what I just created (essentially two lines of code), which seems to work just fine on Chrome/Windows 7. The script that I created gets a handle to the embed object, and then simply focuses it.

To do it yourself, create a new text file named anything.user.js, and in it, place:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Download YouTube FocusFix by adam@papsy.net
// @description Creates hotkey to go to next video in playlist
// @namespace http://googlesystem.blogspot.com
// @include http://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @include https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @match http://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @match https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @author adam@papsy.net
// @version 1.1
// @date 2013-08-01

// GET ARRAY OF EMBED TAGS
var aEmbed = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
// FOCUS FIRST ONE (VIDEO PLAYER)
var bFocus = aEmbed[0].focus();
```

Then install the [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) extension from the Chrome Store.

Once it's installed, open chrome://extensions and drag your anything.user.js file to the page window. It'll prompt you, asking if you wish to install the script - click yes. Then navigate to a YouTube playlist, ensure that autoplay is on and test it out by pressing the [END] key. It will immediately go to the end of the current video, which will trigger the next video.

That's it. You could also create a bookmarklet that points to:

```
javascript:var x=document.getElementsByTagName('embed'); var y = x[0].focus();
```

But that sorta defeats the purpose of using a keyboard shortcut, since you'd have to click the bookmark. I glanced to see if there's anyway to execute a bookmark by hotkey (e.g. in Chrome), but that doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but here is what I did

```
!x::
SetTitleMatchMode 2
IfWinExist, Chrome
{
    WinActivate YouTube
    Send +n
    Send !{Esc} ; Activate previous window
    return
}
```

Edit: 
Controlling via Media which is better

```
+!Left::Send   {Media_Prev}
+!Down::Send   {Media_Play_Pause}
+!Right::Send  {Media_Next}
```

```
shift + alt + left  = Prev Media
shift + alt + down  = Pause Media
shift + alt + right = Next Media
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found an official post [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en) with **Youtube** shortcuts, which also seems to work on Youtube Music.

Instead, there is an unofficial answer by an user with a complete list of shorcuts available in **Youtube Music** [here](https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/180145?hl=en).

#### The following shortcuts are reported from the [**unofficial** post](https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/180145?hl=en) for Youtube Music.

> **Note**: This list is unofficial, may not be complete and change over time.
>
>  Minus is meant that one on main keyboard, next to <kbd>0</kbd> and
> <kbd>=</kbd>, **keypad** is not supported.

There is a list in the player, simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> to see it.

**Playback**

- <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon) => Play/Pause
- <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  => Previous Song
- <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>  => Next Song
- <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>  => Go 10 seconds back
- <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>  => Go 10 seconds forward
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>  => Go 1 second back
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>  => Go 1 second forward
- <kbd>S</kbd>  => Shuffle current queue
- <kbd>R</kbd>  => Switch repeat modes

**General**

- <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) => Volume - 10
- <kbd>=</kbd> => Volume + 10
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) => Dislike Song and go to next
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> => Like Song
- <kbd>F</kbd> => Fullscreen
- <kbd>M</kbd> => Mute/Unmute
- <kbd>Q</kbd> => Maximize/Minimize Player with queue

**Navigation**

- <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> => Go to home
- <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> => Go to Library
- <kbd>G</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> => Go to Hotlist
- <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>(comma) => Go to Settings
- <kbd>/</kbd> => Search
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> => Show keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. Google search did not provide any links that talk about keyboard shortcuts for the playlist bar. Even their help page does not mention any keyboard shortcuts. If there were keyboard shortcuts, hovering over the next/prev video buttons would show a tooltip with the keyboard key to press.

I was thinking that there'd be a browser extension that mapped screen-region clicks to a keystroke but I couldn't find anything either. If it did exist, you could have used that as a workaround.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it's a solution for you, but try http://www.streamkeys.com/guide.html

The chrome app also has some settings, unfortunately none for the previous track, but everything else is there.